# HTML/CSS development without loading project resources

Tags: html, css, web, gruntjs, development-environment

I have this dilemma where I spend most of my development time making minor css/html changes in a large project, but spend 30+ seconds waiting for my build tool (grunt) to implement the changes, load all of the front-end project resources (bootstrap, etc), and then reload then reload the page.

My question is about the development environments others set up to ONLY make html/css changes. Do you use codepen and copy the project files over after you create your finished project? Do you just run the front-end from your machine and load it in a web-browser? Am I missing something entirely in my development process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do small changes on element inspect from chrome then implement it. After a lot of changes I reload.

Also, there are some IDE that supports live changes like JetBrains

Answer (score 0):

Just build and test the frontend using placeholders for your server generated data. When you are ready, incorporate the back end.